# How to remove interface language from magento admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, locale

how to remove all language from magento admin panel from footer left drop down.
(interface locale). **i want to set only two language in this**

Comment: try this http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-change-magentos-interface-locale-dropdown-in-admin-section/

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is that the dropdown is generated dynamically based on hardcoded locales.

Basically `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Page_Footer` generates the select with the following code:

```
public function getLanguageSelect()
{
    $locale  = Mage::app()->getLocale();
    $cacheId = self::LOCALE_CACHE_KEY . $locale->getLocaleCode();
    $html    = Mage::app()->loadCache($cacheId);

    if (!$html) {
        $html = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/html_select')
            ->setName('locale')
            ->setId('interface_locale')
            ->setTitle(Mage::helper('page')->__('Interface Language'))
            ->setExtraParams('style="width:200px"')
            ->setValue($locale->getLocaleCode())
            ->setOptions($locale->getTranslatedOptionLocales())
            ->getHtml();
        Mage::app()->saveCache($html, $cacheId, array(self::LOCALE_CACHE_TAG), self::LOCALE_CACHE_LIFETIME);
    }

    return $html;
}
```

You can notice the `$locale->getTranslatedOptionLocales()` is used to generate the options.

And the allowed locales are hardcoded directly under `Mage_Core_Model_Locale_Config` :

```
protected $_allowedLocales      = array(
    'af_ZA' /*Afrikaans (South Africa)*/,   'ar_DZ' /*Arabic (Algeria)*/,       'ar_EG' /*Arabic (Egypt)*/,
    'ar_KW' /*Arabic (Kuwait)*/,            'ar_MA' /*Arabic (Morocco)*/,       'ar_SA' /*Arabic (Saudi Arabia)*/,
    'az_AZ' /*Azerbaijani (Azerbaijan)*/,   'be_BY' /*Belarusian (Belarus)*/,   'bg_BG' /*Bulgarian (Bulgaria)*/,
    'bn_BD' /*Bengali (Bangladesh)*/,       'bs_BA' /*Bosnian (Bosnia)*/,       'ca_ES' /*Catalan (Catalonia)*/,
    'cs_CZ' /*Czech (Czech Republic)*/,     'cy_GB' /*Welsh (United Kingdom)*/, 'da_DK' /*Danish (Denmark)*/,
    'de_AT' /*German (Austria)*/,           'de_CH' /*German (Switzerland)*/,   'de_DE' /*German (Germany)*/,
    'el_GR' /*Greek (Greece)*/,             'en_AU' /*English (Australian)*/,   'en_CA' /*English (Canadian)*/,
    'en_GB' /*English (United Kingdom)*/,   'en_NZ' /*English (New Zealand)*/,  'en_US' /*English (United States)*/,
    'es_AR' /*Spanish (Argentina)*/,        'es_CO' /*Spanish (Colombia)*/,     'es_PA' /*Spanish (Panama)*/,
    'gl_ES' /*Galician (Galician)*/,        'es_CR' /*Spanish (Costa Rica)*/,   'es_ES' /*Spanish (Spain)*/,
    'es_MX' /*Spanish (Mexico)*/,           'es_EU' /*Basque (Basque)*/,        'es_PE' /*Spanish (Peru)*/,
    'et_EE' /*Estonian (Estonia)*/,         'fa_IR' /*Persian (Iran)*/,         'fi_FI' /*Finnish (Finland)*/,
    'fil_PH' /*Filipino (Philippines)*/,    'fr_CA' /*French (Canada)*/,        'fr_FR' /*French (France)*/,
    'gu_IN' /*Gujarati (India)*/,           'he_IL' /*Hebrew (Israel)*/,        'hi_IN' /*Hindi (India)*/,
    'hr_HR' /*Croatian (Croatia)*/,         'hu_HU' /*Hungarian (Hungary)*/,    'id_ID' /*Indonesian (Indonesia)*/,
    'is_IS' /*Icelandic (Iceland)*/,        'it_CH' /*Italian (Switzerland)*/,  'it_IT' /*Italian (Italy)*/,
    'ja_JP' /*Japanese (Japan)*/,           'ka_GE' /*Georgian (Georgia)*/,     'km_KH' /*Khmer (Cambodia)*/,
    'ko_KR' /*Korean (South Korea)*/,       'lo_LA' /*Lao (Laos)*/,             'lt_LT' /*Lithuanian (Lithuania)*/,
    'lv_LV' /*Latvian (Latvia)*/,           'mk_MK' /*Macedonian (Macedonia)*/, 'mn_MN' /*Mongolian (Mongolia)*/,
    'ms_MY' /*Malaysian (Malaysia)*/,       'nl_NL' /*Dutch (Netherlands)*/,    'nb_NO' /*Norwegian BokmГ_l (Norway)*/,
    'nn_NO' /*Norwegian Nynorsk (Norway)*/, 'pl_PL' /*Polish (Poland)*/,        'pt_BR' /*Portuguese (Brazil)*/,
    'pt_PT' /*Portuguese (Portugal)*/,      'ro_RO' /*Romanian (Romania)*/,     'ru_RU' /*Russian (Russia)*/,
    'sk_SK' /*Slovak (Slovakia)*/,          'sl_SI' /*Slovenian (Slovenia)*/,   'sq_AL' /*Albanian (Albania)*/,
    'sr_RS' /*Serbian (Serbia)*/,           'sv_SE' /*Swedish (Sweden)*/,       'sw_KE' /*Swahili (Kenya)*/,
    'th_TH' /*Thai (Thailand)*/,            'tr_TR' /*Turkish (Turkey)*/,       'uk_UA' /*Ukrainian (Ukraine)*/,
    'vi_VN' /*Vietnamese (Vietnam)*/,       'zh_CN' /*Chinese (China)*/,        'zh_HK' /*Chinese (Hong Kong SAR)*/,
    'zh_TW' /*Chinese (Taiwan)*/,           'es_CL' /*Spanich (Chile)*/,        'lo_LA' /*Laotian*/,
    'es_VE' /*Spanish (Venezuela)*/,        'en_IE' /*English (Ireland)*/,
);
```

So to me the easiest way of doing it would be to create a module to rewrite the footer block as I'm pretty sure the `Mage_Core_Model_Locale_Config` is used in several other places in the software.

So create `app/etc/modules/Vendor_Module.xml`

```
<config>
  <modules>
    <Vendor_Module>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Vendor_Module>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Then you can create `app/code/local/Vendor/Module/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Vendor_Module>
      <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Vendor_Module>
  </modules>
  <global>
        <blocks>  
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <page_footer>Vendor_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Page_Footer</page_footer>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global> 
</config>
```

Then you can create `app/code/local/Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Page/Footer.php`

```
<?php

class Vendor_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Page_Footer extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Page_Footer 
{
    public function getLanguageSelect()
    {
        $locale  = Mage::app()->getLocale();
        $cacheId = self::LOCALE_CACHE_KEY . $locale->getLocaleCode();
        $html    = Mage::app()->loadCache($cacheId);

        // Generate your own options
        $options = $this->_getCustomLocale();

        if (!$html) {
            $html = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/html_select')
                ->setName('locale')
                ->setId('interface_locale')
                ->setTitle(Mage::helper('page')->__('Interface Language'))
                ->setExtraParams('style="width:200px"')
                ->setValue($locale->getLocaleCode())
                ->setOptions($options)
                ->getHtml();
            Mage::app()->saveCache($html, $cacheId, array(self::LOCALE_CACHE_TAG), self::LOCALE_CACHE_LIFETIME);
        }

        return $html;
    }

    protected function _getCustomLocale()
    {
         $languages = Mage:getModel('core/locale')->getLocale()->getTranslationList('language', Mage:getModel('core/locale')->getLocale());
         $countries = Mage:getModel('core/locale')->getCountryTranslationList();
         $customLocales = array('en_US', 'fr_FR');
         $customOptions = array();
         foreach($customLocales as $customLocale) {
             $data = explode('_', $customLocale);
             $label = ucwords(Mage:getModel('core/locale')->getLocale()->getTranslation($data[0], 'language', $customLocale))
                        . ' (' . Mage:getModel('core/locale')->getLocale()->getTranslation($data[1], 'country', $customLocale) . ') / '
                        . $languages[$data[0]] . ' (' . $countries[$data[1]] . ')';
             $customOptions[] = array(
                    'value' => $customLocale,
                    'label' => $label
                );
         }
         return $this->_sortOptionArray($customOptions);
    }

    protected function _sortOptionArray($option)
    {
        $data = array();
        foreach ($option as $item) {
            $data[$item['value']] = $item['label'];
        }
        asort($data);
        $option = array();
        foreach ($data as $key => $label) {
            $option[] = array(
               'value' => $key,
               'label' => $label
            );
        }
        return $option;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to replace my example array `array('en_US', 'fr_FR');` with the array containing your locale codes.